# Rasterizing shapefiles with GDAL and Python?

Tags: gdal, python-2.7, rasterization, gdal-rasterize

I am trying to rasterize a shapefile, and write values from a specific column of the shapefile into the resulting GTiff.

Here is what I've done so far, but that only creates a GTiff of zeros.

```
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import ogr
from osgeo import gdalconst

ndsm = 'base.tif'
shp = 'polygon.shp'
data = gdal.Open(ndsm, gdalconst.GA_ReadOnly)
geo_transform = data.GetGeoTransform()
source_layer = data.GetLayer()
x_min = geo_transform[0]
y_max = geo_transform[3]
x_max = x_min + geo_transform[1] * data.RasterXSize
y_min = y_max + geo_transform[5] * data.RasterYSize
x_res = data.RasterXSize
y_res = data.RasterYSize
mb_v = ogr.Open(shp)
mb_l = mb_v.GetLayer()
pixel_width = geo_transform[1]
target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create('my.tiff', x_res, y_res, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
target_ds.SetGeoTransform((x_min, pixel_width, 0, y_min, 0, pixel_width))
band = target_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
NoData_value = -999999
band.SetNoDataValue(NoData_value)
band.FlushCache()
gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], mb_l, options=["ATTRIBUTE=hedgerow"])
```

How do I get the values of column 'hedgerow' into the GTiff?
In addition, I have to use the option 'ALL_TOUCHED=TRUE' with RasterizeLayer. How does the `gdal.RasterizeLayer` call has to look with both options in it?

Edit: using `gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], mb_l, options=["ATTRIBUTE=hedgerow", "ALL_TOUCHED=TRUE"])` runs without any problem, yet I only get zeros.

Comment: I think that you only need this line `target_ds = None` at the botton of your code (see my answer).

Comment: What will ```target_ds = None``` do?

Comment: Close the flow of data. In my case, if I don't use that instruction I get a GTiff of zeros.

Comment: By the way, you should use absolute paths to shapefile and raster. The problem can be there.

Comment: Hmm, I changed for absolute paths. Still all zeros.

Comment: In the end it really was only the ```target_ds = None```. It works now and as long as I am creating the raster in memory it is fast. As soon as I have to write to disk it becomes three-times slower.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I tried out your code, slightly modified by me for adapting it to mi data (adding your 'hedgerow' field to my shapefile), and it ran well with only add to your code the line: `target_ds = None`.

```
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import ogr
from osgeo import gdalconst

ndsm = '/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/utah_demUTM2.tif'
shp = '/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/polygon8.shp'
data = gdal.Open(ndsm, gdalconst.GA_ReadOnly)
geo_transform = data.GetGeoTransform()
#source_layer = data.GetLayer()
x_min = geo_transform[0]
y_max = geo_transform[3]
x_max = x_min + geo_transform[1] * data.RasterXSize
y_min = y_max + geo_transform[5] * data.RasterYSize
x_res = data.RasterXSize
y_res = data.RasterYSize
mb_v = ogr.Open(shp)
mb_l = mb_v.GetLayer()
pixel_width = geo_transform[1]
output = '/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/my.tif'
target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(output, x_res, y_res, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
target_ds.SetGeoTransform((x_min, pixel_width, 0, y_min, 0, pixel_width))
band = target_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
NoData_value = -999999
band.SetNoDataValue(NoData_value)
band.FlushCache()
gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], mb_l, options=["ATTRIBUTE=hedgerow"])

target_ds = None
```

This is the condition before running the code:

[image]

After running the code I got:

[image]

Shapefile was adequately rasterized by 'hedgerow' field.

Comment: Sorry, adding the ```target_ds = None``` doesn't change my result.
I'm not sure if there can be a problem with the extent or not. The shapefile has a much bigger spatial extent than the GTiff where I retrieve the extent from. However, the GTiff I create using ```gdal.RasterizeLayer``` has the right extent.

I also checked the layer retrieved from the shapefile, after opening it, and there are more than 300.000 objects in it. I also checked that the column 'hedgerow' is actually there, and it is. 

Is there a specific format the 'hedgerow' column has to have?

Comment: I saw that your raster data type is byte so, my 'hedgerow' column was integer.

Comment: Followed the code and implemented in my project. I got an error as follows: AttributeError: 'Dataset' object  has no attribute 'SetGeotransform'

Comment: This answer was produced four and a half years ago (by using QGIS 2). Several things could have changed. I will try in QGIS 3 for evaluating which issues are playing.

Answer (score 2):

It's my first time writing here, but hope I might give you some insight. I used the code from your post, with some minor changes it worked… kind of. I checked the correlation matrices that I get by comparing some of my classification data with data rasterized in the QGIS tool and raster generated by this code. Raster generated by your code had kappa coefficient near 0.4, while that generated by QGIS was near 0.9. I think the problem lies somewhere in

```
    target_ds.SetGeoTransform((x_min, pixel_width, 0, y_min, 0, pixel_width))
```

Using .GetGeoTransform() solved the problem for me (got same correlation matrices as from QGIS data)

```
    target_ds.SetGeoTransform(data.GetGeTransform())
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to xunilks answer.
Add to georeference the output:

```
target_ds.SetProjection(data.GetProjection())
```