# Rasterizing by attribute in rasterio

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio

According to [Rasterizing shapefiles with GDAL and Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212795) it seems that `gdal` allows rasterization of a layer according to a certain attribute

`ds = gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], source_layer, options = ["ATTRIBUTE=ID"])`

I would like to rasterize a layer with small square polygon geometries using `rasterio`

[image]

`rasterio` has a `features.rasterize` method [(see docs)](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.features.html), but it seems to only be able to output numpy arrays with 1's where the polygons occur. Since `rasterio` is a higher level library than `gdal` I am a bit surprised that selecting an attribute to burn the raster with is not supported functionality.

Is there any built-in method in `rasterio` to burn a raster by an attribute from the original vector layer?

Comment: Can you not pre-filter the "shapes" you pass to features.rasterize to include only the shapes with the desired attributes? As for the "1's where the polygons occur," isn't that what you want? I.e. a binary raster containing only pixels where your feature is present.

Comment: No, my polygons have an attribute which is float type and varies for each polygon. I am not looking for a binary raster but rather a raster with values from my polygon attribute

Comment: It looks like you can specify the value in the shapes object you pass: "default_value (int or float, optional) – Used as value for all geometries, *if not provided in shapes*." The shapes input says "shapes (iterable of (geometry, value) pairs or iterable over)..." so you just need to pass the float value along with each geometry as a tuple.

Comment: Indeed. I only realized this after writing the question... If you like you can provide that as your answer.

Comment: However I see that there is also no place to specify the nodata value for this newly created raster dataset

Comment: Oh never mind, theres a `fill` value argument which can be set to the nodata value for the template raster dataset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inputs to `features.rasterize` include

> shapes (iterable of (geometry, value) pairs or iterable over) –
>   geometries. geometry can either be an object that implements the geo
>   interface or GeoJSON-like object.

So you can just pass tuples of `(geom, value)`, where `value` is the attribute value you wish to burn into the raster.

Answer (score 1):

To give an example if you have col set to the column you want to rasterize

```
if col:
    shapes = ((geom,value) for geom, value in zip(dataframe.geometry, dataframe[col]))
else: 
    shapes = dataframe.geometry.values
    
varray = rasterize(shapes,
                   out_shape=(dst_height, dst_width),
                   transform=dst_transform,
                   fill=fill,
                   default_value=default_value,
                   all_touched=all_touched,
                   dtype=dtype)
```