# Calculate stats with GDAL Python or rasterio for each bands

Tags: python, modis, evi, cell-statistics

I have MODIS EVI file stacking with 10bands.
I use Python 3 in Spyder.

I'm trying to rastersize shapefile and do mask to my MODIS EVI.

This is my script :

```
import os
import glob
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.ndimage
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import ogr
import rasterio as rio 
import fiona
import rasterio
import rasterio.mask

inDir = 'D:/projetp/Doy_2000/'
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
os.chdir(inDir)  

with fiona.open("C:/Doy2000/1996n.shp", "r") as shapefile:
    shapes = [feature["geometry"] for feature in shapefile]

with rasterio.open("D:/projetp/Doy_2000/MODIS_EVI_2000.tif") as src:
    out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, shapes, crop=True)
    out_meta = src.meta

out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
                 "height": out_image.shape[1],
                 "width": out_image.shape[2],
                 "transform": out_transform})

with rasterio.open("MODIS_MASK_2000.tif", "w", **out_meta) as dest:
    dest.write(out_image)
```

when i whrite out_image in spyder i hade this resultas

```
print(out_image)
[[[   0    0    0 ...    0    0    0]
  [   0    0 1682 ...    0    0    0]
  [   0 1841 1888 ...    0    0    0]
  ...
  [   0    0    0 ... 2180    0    0]
  [   0    0    0 ... 4033    0    0]
  [   0    0    0 ...    0    0    0]]

 [[   0    0    0 ...    0    0    0]
  [   0    0 1659 ...    0    0    0]
  [   0 1829 1830 ...    0    0    0]
  ...
  [   0    0    0 ... 3953    0    0]
  [   0    0    0 ... 4627    0    0]
  [   0    0    0 ...    0    0    0]]

 [[   0    0    0 ...    0    0    0]
  [   0    0 1706 ...    0    0    0]
  [   0 1547 1740 ...    0    0    0]
  ...
  [   0    0    0 ... 4419    0    0]
  [   0    0    0 ... 4564    0    0]
  [   0    0    0 ...    0    0    0]]

 ...

 [[   0    0    0 ...    0    0    0]
  [   0    0 1998 ...    0    0    0]
  [   0 2255 1841 ...    0    0    0]
  ...
  [   0    0    0 ... 3339    0    0]
  [   0    0    0 ... 3501    0    0]
  [   0    0    0 ...    0    0    0]]

 [[   0    0    0 ...    0    0    0]
  [   0    0 1992 ...    0    0    0]
  [   0 3337 3337 ...    0    0    0]
  ...
  [   0    0    0 ... 2058    0    0]
  [   0    0    0 ... 2080    0    0]
  [   0    0    0 ...    0    0    0]]

 [[   0    0    0 ...    0    0    0]
  [   0    0 7913 ...    0    0    0]
  [   0 7659 7294 ...    0    0    0]
  ...
  [   0    0    0 ... 5014    0    0]
  [   0    0    0 ... 4626    0    0]
  [   0    0    0 ...    0    0    0]]]
```

And when I visualize my out_image in QGIS I have this result

[image]

Do I need to delete the value 0 or not? And how can I show my out_images in Python?

The values are so big.  How can I apply a scale factor *1/10000 to have values (-1,1)? 
- How can I calculate statistics ( mean of pixel of my out_image just inside the area not in black area  )! Because I need just mean of pixel for all bands to export after in dataframe!

Comment: These questions relate more to numpy [indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html) and [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) than anything else, so read up on those topics.  You can do things like `np.mean(out_image[out_image != 0])` to mask out zeros when calculating stats.

Comment: @ need i to delete the value 0 or not ? thank u

Comment: https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/masks.html

Comment: @Luke thanks but in my mask.tif i don't have 0 in all values is just for black pixel i need just remove it

Comment: @Luke how can i do that change it to another value cause i need just the area in cercle not in the black area !?

Comment: @Luke i read the link now but please need some help to calcul statis ( mean value in the area ) for all bands of my raster  i need use loop fonction but i don't know how